# Translucent spots on leaves

Tags: diagnosis, pest-control, leaves, pest-damage, damage

Recently, several of my plants have developed these translucent spots on their leaves:

[image: A leaf with a translucent spot[1]]

What is causing this? What should I do?

Comment: My guess would be a bacterial infection. Maybe someone else can give a better answer if you provide some more details. What types of plants? what are the growing conditions? Age of plants and how long you've had them? How do you maintain them.

Comment: Sometimes gastropods (slugs/snails) manage to eat not quite all the way through the leaf - try looking at night with a flashlight (underside as well as on top) - then again, the brown bit puts me in mind of mosaic virus.

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY This particular plant is a bean plant. It's also happened on corn amongst others.

Comment: Looks like insect damage to me.

Answer (score 3):

I would ignore the spots. I find them regularly, but they don't expand, and it seem not to damage the plants or reduce harvest.

Just check them regularly, and if they take only a small fraction of surface (compared to all other leaves), just ignore them.

On new plants (so with less leaves), I would worry a little bit more, but I have no solution other than than planting more beans and later selecting the better plants.

Comment: But I welcome a better solution.